# Change image when hovering over li and keep that image permanent using CSS

Tags: html, css, image, hover, html-lists

For the life of me I can't figure it out. Essentially there is an image place holder that loads on page visit. Then when I hover over option 1, 2 or 3 a new image takes its place and becomes permanent until I hover another option. Is this possible?

```
<div>
[Image - Loads on Visit]
[Image 2- Hidden until hover on li]
[Image 3- Hidden until hover on li]
</div>  

<div>
<ul>
<li>Option 1</li>
<li>Option 2</li>
<li>Option 3</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another way to do it with jQuery. You will have to load in your own images to really see it work.

Here is the working fiddle!

https://jsfiddle.net/ur7tns7L/

I took away

```
    $(#element).on("mouseleave",function(){


});
```

This makes the image permanent until another is hovered over.

Comment: awesome. What do I need to add to make the image from the hovered over li permanent until I hover over another li?

Comment: See revised version above

Comment: Noah, stellar! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Your best way to do this would be with JavaScript. jQuery will make your job even easier. Do something like this for each of your images:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('li.list-class-1').mouseover(function(){
        $('.img-1').css({"display": "block"});
        $('.img-2').css({"display": "none"});
        $('.img-3').css({"display": "none"});
    });
    $('li.list-class-2').mouseover(function(){
        $('.img-2').css({"display": "block"});
        $('.img-1').css({"display": "none"});
        $('.img-3').css({"display": "none"});
    });
    $('li.list-class-3').mouseover(function(){
        $('.img-3').css({"display": "block"});
        $('.img-1').css({"display": "none"});
        $('.img-2').css({"display": "none"});
    });
});
```

This code just sets the display of the relevant image when you mouse over the list items. you need to give some classes (or IDs) to your list items and images.

Comment: Tried to make a Demo here [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/2Lfx1Lmq/) but can't get it to work. Could you provide some input?

Comment: You just used id instead of class for the elements.

Working JSFiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/2Lfx1Lmq/3/